# Caloric Mimicry

Tags: evolution, ecology, molecular-evolution

I was thinking about natural "zero calorie" sweetners and how these compounds could come to be via evolution. I was specifically thinking about monk fruit. While artificial selection likely played a role in the life history of the modern cultivated variety, this plant still needed to initially possess sweetness traits for humans to select. It seems to me to be an interesting case of mimicry — copy the palatability signal of caloric value of other fruits while not devoting valuable resources to creating equivalent amounts of sugars —because it depends on those other fruits/foods being consumed often enough to sustain the propagating organism. This makes it hard to classify the nature to the relationship in the propagator-mimick-mimicked triangle: the propagator-mimick relationship may be read as parasitic, commensal or mutualistic depending how we consider the value of non-caloric nutritional factors for (reproductive) success. Same can be said for the mimick-mimicked relationship, as both benefit from the strengthening of the sweetness signal, but the true signal might in fact benefit more under complete knowledge on the part of the propagator. As a strategy, it is also very interesting because it requires a generalist propagator in an ecosystem with a certain amount of biodiversity, so it seems more likely for this relationship to emerge in nutrient rich environments than poorer ones.

Can anyone think of other examples and are there any existing examinations of similar relationships in the literature?

Comment: Nice idea. Plants generally can afford to be energetically wasteful, so I doubt we will see examples of such a high risk / low reward strategy

Comment: Interesting proposition. Mogroside appears to have a very complex chemical structure which I would of thought to be very metabolically expensive to create. Although it is 250 times sweeter than sucrose is there any way to quantify if it is > 250 times less expensive to create, I am sure there are many ways to quantify metabolic expense beyond carbon to carbon comparisons etc?

Comment: Synsepalum Dulcificum's fruit contains miraculin which makes acids taste sweet. A small amount of citric acid combined with a tiny amount of miraculin will taste like a lot of sugar.

Comment: @KaPy3141: Proteins are expensive (nitrogen) for plants and valuable to animals. Even Drosophila can have sugar/calorie hunger and/or protein hunger. So a plant that mimics a lot of protein using a much smaller quantity of some compound (which could also be a peptide) maybe. But the main parts of the plant that are "designed" to be eaten (the fruit and nectar) aren't very proteinaceous.

Comment: @JEJS So it could just be a energetically more expensive strategy that becomes successful in a environment where the propagator, here humans, has evolved receptiveness to sweetness. But since mogrosides can act as antioxidants, maybe the benefits outweigh the costs and the sweetness mimicry is an additional bonus?

Comment: @KevinKostlan Interesting. Is that the same as "miracle berry"?

Comment: @KevinKostlan: Nice point about Nitrogen. I fully agree: Basically, fruits can be assumed to be nutritiously cost-optimized, while ample access to CO2 and sunlight allow higher 'generosity', in terms of calories (sugars).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, carrion flowers for example mimic the scent of rotting flesh to attract flies which will then carry their pollen to other carrion plants.  With sugar specifically though, I'm not sure it would work as well because I believe the fake sugar in drinks like zero calorie soda are actually just as energetically expensive as natural sugar to produce.  So while a plant producing artificial sweetener might not give us any calories, it still has to expend a bunch of calories to produce it.